# How to pass interval in mybatis from annotations?

Tags: postgresql, annotations, mybatis

I am using myBatis through annotations to fetch data from my server. Trying to get the data **n** days old, the annotation :

```
@Select("SELECT o.title from user_order o where current_date - date_trunc('day', o.dateoforder) < '#{n} days'")
ArrayList<OrderRecord> getOrderHistory(@Param("n") int n);
```

returns error:

> The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.  Error
>   querying database. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The
>   column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.

Also,

```
@Select("SELECT o.title from user_order o where current_date - date_trunc('day', o.dateoforder) < #{n}")
ArrayList<OrderRecord> getOrderHistory(@Param("n") String n);
```

produces the similar error when n is something like "5 days".

What data-type is being expected?

I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4):

Mybatis is expecting an interval parameter and cannot cast the integer or String into it automatically.

An object of the type ***PGInterval*** needs to be passed.

```
PGInterval pginterval = new PGInterval("5 days");
```

and the annotation must be:

```
@Select("SELECT o.title from user_order o where current_date - date_trunc('day', o.dateoforder) < #{n}")
ArrayList<OrderRecord> getOrderHistory(@Param("n") PGInterval n);
```

Answer (score 2):

Per [this link](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/43D53825.10107@opencloud.com), you can also cast the value to an interval in your SQL. For example, this is what I am using in my application: `now() + CAST(#{my_interval} AS INTERVAL)`.

where 'my_interval' is the '5 day' string.